# how to Install Fipy on Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, installation, package, fipy

I would like to install Fipy on Python3.3 (Windows 7 or Linux/ubuntu-mint), is possible? I need to use Fipy for improving my python3.3 coding. Do I have to translate that in python 2.7 ? 
Please does anyone know? any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

FiPy has been able to run under Python 3.x since last summer. Only the SciPy solvers are supported (PySparse and PyTrilinos are not ready for Py3k to the best of my knowledge).

See http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#running-under-python-3 for directions. I have only tried it on Mac OS X, but it should work on Linux and Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, FiPy does not support Python 3. You need to either use Python 2 or help update FiPy to support Python 3. Contact the authors about that.

Comment: ... I tried to instal 3to2 tool to convert 3.3 to 2.7 but I didn't manage ... do you have any idea?

Comment: @user1640255: Contact the authors of FiPy. Read http://python3porting.com/ This is not a ten minute job.